# React Native : WebView unresponsive webpage

Tags: react-native

I am implementing `react-native-webview` but the page has infinite right scroll. I tried to give width equal to device-width, but still the issue persists.

```js
<WebView
  source={{
    uri : 'https://firstam.com/privacy-policy/',
  }}
  startInLoadingState
  useWebKit
  scalesPageToFit
  style={styles.bodyContainer}
/>
```

styles.js

```js
export default StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaViewContainer: {
    width: width,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.backgroundColor,
  },
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.snow,
  },
  bodyContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: height - 60,
    padding: 20,
  },
});
```

Here is a screenshot for same. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z1MV.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` between head tag in your privacy-policy.html

Comment: I tried ```injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=2.0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}```. But the page is zoomed out.